# Why the Mean absolute error not going down in fully feed forward network after doing VAE?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to build a prediction model, initially I did Variational Autoencoder and reduced the features from 2100 to 64.

Now having (5000 X 64) samples for training and (2000 X 64) for testing with that I tried to build a Fully feed forward or MLP network, but as a result when my mean absolute error reaches 161 it's not going down. I tried varying all hyper-parameters and also the hidden layers but no use.

Can anyone suggest what would be the reason and How I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, training a neural network can be a bit tricky. Performance of the network after training (even the training process itself) depends on a large number of factors. Secondly, you have to be more specific about the your dataset (the problem rather) in your question.
Just by looking at your question, what can be said is ...

- What is the range of values in your data ? Having a **mean** absolute error the magnitude of your error being 161 is quite high. It seems like you have large values in your data. (Try normalizing the data, i.e. subtract the mean and divide by variance of each of your features/variables.
- How you initialized the weights of your network ? Training performance depends very much on the initial weight values. A wrong initialization can lead to a local minimum. (Try initializing using Glorot's initialization method)
- You have reduced the dimensionality from 2100 to 64. Isn't this too much? (actually it might be okay to do but it really depends on your data).